# Can I take in.xyz as bundle ID?

Tags: ios, naming-conventions, bundle-identifier

Its is a simple Question but I didn't find any answer related to that. I am developing an App and its bundleId starts with in.projectName . I want to ask Is this compulsory to give bundleID com.projectName or I can Give whatever I want in DNS format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not compulsory you can use in.xyz name in Organization identifier [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can write the following way.

```
com.in.projectName
```